# Crashing when using QAbstractTableModel with QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Since it appears there is no "dedicated" Abstract Model "designed" purposely for QTreeView (for `QListView` there is `QAbstractListModel` and for QTableView there is `QAbstractTableModel`) and since I need to be able to display the headers I opted to use Table's Abstract model: `QAbstractTableModel` with 'QTreeView'. The code runs fine but if a plus signed is clicked it crashes immidiately. Shouldn't be `QAbstractTableModel` used with 'QTreeView'? What Abstract model to use?

[image]

```
import os,sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
elements={'Animals':{1:'Bison',2:'Panther',3:'Elephant'},'Birds':{1:'Duck',2:'Hawk',3:'Pigeon'},'Fish':{1:'Shark',2:'Salmon',3:'Piranha'}}

class Model(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self.items=[] 
        self.modelDict={}
    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)   
    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0<=index.row()<len(self.items)): return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role==QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:          return QtCore.QVariant(self.items[index.row()])
    def buildItems(self):
        totalItems=self.rowCount()
        for key in self.modelDict:    
            self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), totalItems+1, 0)
            self.items.append(key)
            self.endInsertRows()

class TreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TreeView, self).__init__()
        self.model= Model()
        self.model.modelDict=elements
        self.model.buildItems()
        self.setModel(self.model)
        self.show()       

window=TreeView()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `QAbstractTableModel` properly with a `QTreeView`, as that class is only for `QTableView`. You must instead inherit [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html), (which is what both `QAbstractTableModel` and `QAbstractListModel` inherit), and implement `index()`, `parent()`, `rowCount()`, `columnCount()`, and `data()`, as described in the [subclassing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing) section of Qt's fine manual. For a `QTreeView`, `parent()` in specific is very important to pay attention to, as it tells the `QTreeView` if an item is at the top level or if it's a child of another item in the tree.

I believe the primary motivation for not having a `QAbstractTreeModel` class in Qt is because you would need to override all of these methods to create a properly expressive tree model, already.

Comment: I think I stick to QTableView then. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: Thanks, I edited my answer. I got the right link at least, even if I got the name of the class wrong :)

Comment: @JeffreyPfau I think it isn't right to say that "You cannot use `QAbstractTableModel` properly with a `QTreeView`, as that class is only for `QTableView`". For one, at the qt tutorial, after discussing a `QAbstractTableModel`, says "You can convert the example above into an application with a tree view. Simply replace QTableView with QTreeView, which results in a read/write tree. No changes have to be made to the model." That is, the doc supports the claim that views can display models of a different type. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html#3-1-treeview.

Comment: Turned my last comment into question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308309/display-data-from-qabstracttablemodel-in-qtreeview

Comment: @neuronet It's strange that that tutorial says that, since the [manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstracttablemodel.html#details) clearly says "Since [QAbstractTableView] model provides a more specialized interface than QAbstractItemModel, it is not suitable for use with tree views"

Comment: @Jeffrey yes I think the tutorial is misleading, and I actually quoted that line you just mentioned in my answer to the question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27333368/1886357). So you are right in spirit: while you *can* get it to work, you really aren't meant to. :)